# Why does starting a new chapter makes footnotes start at 2?

Tags: footnotes, chapters

Please have a look at the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{unnumbered}
Wombat unnumbered\footnote{Capybara unnumbered}
\chapter{Introduction}
Wombat\footnote{Capybara}
\chapter{C}
\lipsum
\footnote{b}%This would be footnote number 2 as well if called on the first page of the chapter. (Bug is not limited to the first numbered chapter of a document.)
\end{document}
```

`\MakePerPage{footnote}` seems to make the footnote number start at 2 when calling a footnote on the first page of a numbered chapter.

Comment: Are the packages requiring XeTeX (and special fonts) needed to rreproduce the problem? If not, kick them out. Same for biblatex and other packages.

Comment: The actual MWE fits into a comment: `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{report}

\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
a\footnote{b}
\end{document}`

Comment: The problem is situated at `\MakePerPage{footnote}`, but I don't know why.

Comment: Sorry for not providing an MWE straight away, since I never encountered that problem, I thought the issue was coming from a complicated interaction and not just such a simple MWE. I came to the same conclusion as you as I removed more and more packages.

Comment: A real MWE does NOT need `geometry` or those class options ;)

Comment: So where should we start looking from here?

Comment: @TeXnician: I guess those were added to fit the footnote call as well as the footnote on a single embeddable picture

Comment: @nathdwek Yep. I don't like it to scroll own to the bottom of the page checking footnotes. I could have omitted using `geometry` for the job and used `\setlength{\textheight}{9cm}`. As geometry is not cause of the problem, which is pretty obvious for a helper, i left it in there.

Comment: try `\MakePerPage[1]{footnote}`. for explanation see documentation of package.

Comment: @Zarko Check MWE at bottom. Is this a version issue? I am still running TL 15. Nevermind, that MWE is gone.

Comment: @Johannes_B, probably. I use recent MikTeX and just now upload package (I newer use it).

Comment: @TeXnician A real MWE compresses the relevant stuff down, so yes, those options were needed.

Comment: @Zarko: I changed the MWE to not run into problems with `\MakePerPage[0]` and also to show that the issue does not appear on later pages of a chapter. Also I'm on TL16/Debian.

Comment: hm, strange. documentation says: *The starting value must not be less than 1 so that the counter logic can detect the reset of a counter reliably.*  :-(. It seems, that there is some bug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This "bug" was introduced in LaTeX, from `changes.txt`:

> 2015-01-10  David Carlisle
>
> - `ltcounts.dtx`: Reset all within counter levels (latexrelease)

Each LaTeX counter is associated with a counter list. The counter in this list
are reset, if the LaTeX counter is incremented by `\stepcounter`. Thus, if the `chapter` is advanced, then the `section` is reset to zero.

In LaTeX before 2015, this reset operation is done by assigning the counter to zero. Since LaTeX release 2015-01, this is done by setting the counter to -1, followed by `\stepcounter`. The effect is that `\stepcounter` triggers the reset
of the next dependent counters and an advance of counter `chapter` not only resets `section`, but also `subsection`, `subsubsection`, ...

Class `report` adds counter `footnote` to the reset list of `chapter`.

The problem arises with packages like `perpage` or `zref-perpage` that hook
into `\stepcounter`. The hook creates a label to get the current page number
to decide, whether the counter needs to be reset, if the counter is incremented
on a new page. The basic asumption is that `\stepcounter` is only called, if a new number for a new object is needed. This assumption is now violated by the
LaTeX update.

**Workaround:** Use of an older LaTeX via package `latexrelease`:

```
\RequirePackage[2014/05/01]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{unnumbered}
Wombat unnumbered\footnote{Capybara unnumbered}
\chapter{Introduction}
Wombat\footnote{Capybara}
\end{document}
```

**Solution:** The issue is solved by removing `footnote` from the reset list of `chapter`.

The following example uses `zref-perpage`, but should work with package `perpage` the same way, because both packages share the assumption about `\stepcounter` and hook into it.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{zref-perpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\zmakeperpage{footnote}

% Remove counter "footnote" from the reset counter list
% of counter "chapter".
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter*{unnumbered}
Wombat unnumbered\footnote{Capybara unnumbered}
\chapter{Introduction}
Wombat\footnote{Capybara}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I will try it out and probably validate it as soon as I can!

Comment: Another workaround is to use package `footmisc` with option `perpage`.

Comment: It's now fixed in `zref`. `@removefromreset` is not necessary. Just `\usepackage[perpage]{zref}` and later `\zmakeperpage{footnote}` is sufficient.

Comment: You save my day, thanks